# Laravel | Сделать выборку из промежуточной таблицы

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, eloquent

Делал для самообучения блог, в котором посты и **теги связаны между собой через промежуточную таблицу** (pivot table) , соответственно **имеются три таблицы:**

```
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name', 80);
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('show')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name', 80);
    });

    Schema::create('posts_to_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('posts_to_tags_id');
        $table->string('posts_to_tags_type');
    });
```

Есть некоторая **страница на которой расположены теги.**
По логике вещей **необходимо отображать только те теги, у которых есть уже посты,** не выводить же те теги у которых пустые посты.

Для сие решения я нашёл несколько вариантов решения проблемы.

**Первая:**

- сделать выборку из таблицы tags и проверить наличие posts

**Из минусов стоит отметить:**

- прийдётся сделать полную выборку тегов и отсортировать их полностью, что повлечёт за собой лишнюю нагрузку.

---

**Второй вариант:**

- заключается в выборке промежуточной таблицы и последующей выборки значений из неё, выглядит как-то дико я бы даже сказал, но именно этот вариант я не смог доделать так как пришлось обращаться к промежуточной таблице напрямую, а не как обычно через модели таблицы.

**Из минусов:**

- необходимо будет сделать несколько запросов чтобы из промежуточной таблицы получить все используемые теги, а их будет явно больше чем вся табличка tags.

---

Есть ли нормальные варианты для решение текущей задачи или придётся выбирать первый вариант и не ***ахать себе мозг?

---

Чёрт, будто держу в руках ту заветную уточку, при рассказывании всего этого понял что первый вариант выглядит наиболее перспективнее и легче.
**А что думаете вы?**

Answer (score 2):

omg, решение было нелепее самого вопроса.

```
return Tags::whereHas('posts', function($query){
    return $query;
    // etc codeshit..
})->get();
```

Comment: или еще проще `Tags::whereHas('posts')->get();`